# Bounding the $q$-th moment of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: statistics, inequality, moment-problem

I have come across an inequality which confuses me:  Suppose $X$ has a Normal$(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution.  Then

$$
(\mathbb{E}|X|^q)^{1/q} \leq \text{const.} \sqrt{q} \sigma
$$

for $q\geq 1$.

I am having trouble figuring out how to show this.  I know that the Normal$(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution has moments

$$
\mathbb{E}|X|^q = \sigma^q \frac{2^{\frac{q}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{q+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}},
$$
for all non-negative integers $q$.  I think I am missing an upper bound for the Gamma function.  Any help?

Comment: Your problem reduces to showing that $\Gamma((q+1)/2)^{1/q} \leq C \sqrt{q}$. It seems to me that a first step would be to apply the functional equation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ enough times to bring the argument into $[1,2]$; then since $\Gamma$ is bounded there, you are left to bound a factorial-like expression. The desired result is "Stirling-like", so you can try to imitate the proof of Stirling's formula.

Comment: Showing that $\Gamma(s)\leqslant cs^s$ for every $s\geqslant1$ should not be a problem, then using this for $s=\frac{1+q}2$ yields the result.